# output Command Shell in if statment

Tags: c++

I have searched many and read many codes but I do not understand why is the variable(the cmd output) can not be printed to be sure of it
the question might be repetitive but I can not comment on any code I saw as I am below 50 reputation
here is the code I am trying and I am trying to get the output of the cmd and use it in IF statement so of example if it gives error then resend the command

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 FILE *lsofFile_p = popen("adb reboot", "r");

  if (!lsofFile_p)
  {
    return -1;
  }


  char buffer[1024];
  char *line_p = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), lsofFile_p);
  pclose(lsofFile_p);
  printf("\n\n", *lsofFile_p);
}
```

edited photo
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("\n\n", *lsofFile_p);
```

This only prints two `\n`. That's it. Not more, not less. That's why you think that it prints "nothing". Also note that `*lsofFile_p` is undefined behavior because you closed the file the line before, and this invalidates the file pointer.

You probably want to print the line that you read from `lsofFile_p`, which you stored in `buffer`:

```
//'%s' take the second argument of printf and interprets it as a string
printf("%s\n\n", buffer);
```

<sub>Consider using `std::string`, `std::cout`, and other facilities to make your life easier, you don't have to program in C when you are programming in C++.</sub>

Comment: thanks for unnoticed wrong but I tested it for now it gives (null), that means its not reading ?

Comment: @DasserBasyouni Probably, but I made an error, `fgets` stored the result  in `buffer`, not in `line_p`.

Comment: but it still not printing also

Comment: @DasserBasyouni I rarely use `adb`, but maybe `adb reboot` doesn't output anything? Maybe try `adb list` or any other command that you are sure outputs something to `stdout`.

Comment: i have tried a working adb command that must have output C:\\adb connect 192.168.101.11:5555 and not writing to the cmd it self also adb reboot gives error that adb is not command because i did not let the cmd know its path but the code does not printed it or store it in the variable

Comment: @DasserBasyouni I think that's by design. If the command doesn't exist, I think it will output nothing (even though you see "command doesn't exist" in terminal), so `buffer` will be empty. This also explains why `line_p` is `nullptr`.

Comment: no it gives error in the cmd, here is a photo of the error i add it in the question post

Comment: @DasserBasyouni `popen` tries to execute `adb reboot`. There is no command `adb`, so it fails, printing out the error. Because the command failed, `buffer` and `line_p` are empty. Can you please clarify because I don't understand your question?

Comment: ah, i understood that the code reads the command output not the error of the cmd that says that the command is not in the inter, external thankss

Comment: concerning the buffer in if statement can it be used in am coding if (buffer == "error...."){printf("error try again..");}
that is not printing anthing

Comment: @DasserBasyouni Comparing char arrays is done by using `strcmp`. Also, `line_p` is `nullptr` when an error occurred